# Is there a market for life scientists converted to software developers

Tags: software-development

Is there a market for life scientists (biomedical research and related fields) that at some point want a change in their career path and switch to software development? Say the career so far was a MSc degree in a life science discipline, a PhD degree and some limited PostDoc experience in biomedical research with a focus on computational biology and data analysis. Limited experience with actual software development but proficient in python towards data analysis, organizing code at GitHub and ability to pick up new skills and languages as needed as demonstrated by being an autodidact in all coding-related skills so far. Age somewhere mid 30s. What would be fields related to software development that such a person could apply for a job?

Comment: My understanding of academic sciences is that there is a significant opportunity for better utilisation of software systems and automation. Unless you are absolutely sick of your field, you should really look to utilise your existing skills in some way.

Comment: Biomed is a thriving industry actively recruiting qualified people. Why do you want to be a software developer?

Comment: @DJClayworth Well, I have always enjoyed the computer science-related part of my work and I feel like it is something I have a passion for. Actually, if I could go back I would major in CS right away, but never again in life science. So from the skills I have I feel like this is the one I can best exploit.

Comment: It's a difficult transition because you don't actually have software development skills. You have what you refer to as proficiency in 2 technologies. The question is, would a hiring manager consider you proficient? You're starting at the bottom of the software ladder and basically competing with fresh cs grads. You definitely need to have more than a little proficiency and enthusiasm.

Answer (score 1):

Entering keywords:
computational biology , data analysis, and Python in popular job website yielded dozens of hits.

Data Scientist:

```
    Master's degree in a *quantitative discipline* (e.g., Statistics, Operations Research, **Bioinformatics**, Economics, Computational Biology...
    2 years of work experience in data analysis related field.
    Experience with statistical software (e.g., **R, Python**, ...
    PhD degree
```

May need to get a cert, probably R, to move toward Data Scientist. Probably an online mini-degree, Udemy or such, course in Data Science.
Note, above is not in anyway a medical field/biology position.

I would search for statistic, data scientist, type postions.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a market for good computer scientists. However if you switch to just being 'a software developer" you will be up against people with degrees in the subject, possibly advanced degrees, and with five years of experience. Five years is a lot in the CS world. With the skills you have listed you will be looking at entry level and intern positions at best. That will involve a pay cut, and that cut will trail you for a long time.

However you will find that particular industries are always looking for people with adequate software development skills but also the skills needed in their industry.
Two examples:

- I worked for a company writing complex mathematical software, which recruited people with math doctorates to write their core algorithms. Those people didn't need excellent software skills, but the core of their work was writing software. Regular software engineers couldn't do the job. (I know because I was one of the regular software developers in the next door team - my Math Bachelors was enough for me to sometimes understand what these people were doing, but not to do it myself).
- A friend of mine finished his doctorate in physics of microwaves (not the ovens!) and couldn't get an academic position, so he got a job with a firm that made microwave devices (again, not the ovens). He had little software experience, but he is doing a job which mostly involves software development. His knowledge of the field outweighs his software inexperience.

So my advice is **there are always people looking for software development positions where your non-software development skills are valuable**. They are not always easy to find, because they don't advertise in the same places where regular software firms advertise. Instead look at firms that are active in your industry, and look to see if they are advertising for software-related jobs.

One likely place is universities. Researchers often want people to write software for them, and an understanding of the field really helps.

It's perfectly possible to make this transition gradually, finding a position where you are doing *some* software development related to your field and gradually increase the amount that is software development.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult transition to make.

> Is there a market for ... ?

If you mean "do hiring managers actively look for life scientist to fill regular SW dev positions?", the answer is "no".

Hiring managers look for

1. Technical skills required by the specific role
2. Culture fit between candidate and org
3. Organizational awareness & experience in the specific type of business as needed by the role.

The better you map to these requirements, the higher the chance that you get a foot in the door. The key to making a significant career transition is to land the first job in the field leveraging as much of your existing skills and experiences as possible.

Things to consider:

1. Look for jobs that use some of your relevant skills

   1. Something in academia or something that frequently interacts with academia
   2. Something that works with data or topics from life sciences
   3. Something that with data with similar properties or features  where the algorithms you already know may come in handy
   4. Leverage your existing network as much as possible: Who reads the publication you write? Who shows up at conferences and meetings? Who is active on message boards and societies you are part of, etc.
2. Make sure you learn about "professional" dev practices. Code architecture and structure, unit testing, nightly builds, release processes & life cycle, tools like Jira & Confluence, schedule and delivery management, requirements capture, scrum, etc. Any real examples of your work you can point to here would be quite helpful.
3. Have a good story to tell about the reason you want to change.

The better you can hit these points, the easier it will be to land the first job. Once you are "in" things get a lot easier: you start accumulating relevant experiences and skill and build a network in your new field.

This may take some considerable effort and time (and could be frustrating at times). You are competing with people at the same skill level who are considerably younger and fit most target profiles a lot better. Patience and diligence is the key here.

Good luck.

P.S. I did a similar transition (post doc to industry at 34) and it worked out great. My "way in" was the network that I had and finding a company that had strong business interest in my field of research.